# Force HTTPS on everything except one category pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In `.htaccess` I have this code to force everything to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

But I want to allow traffic that is coming from

```
http://www.example.com/video/*
```

To stay on HTTP and redirect from HTTPS to HTTP if needed.

Comment: So you need either an additional negative `RewriteCond` testing for that pattern, or you implement an exception pass through `RewriteRule` before the general rewrite rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent `/video/<whatever>` being redirected to HTTPS then you can modify your existing `RewriteRule` *pattern* to exclude such URLs. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^video/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This will match any URL *except* those starting `/video/`. (The `!` prefix negates the regex.)

> ...and redirect from HTTPS to HTTP if needed.

To do this, add an additional rule. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^video/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

The check against the `X-Forwarded-Proto` implies you are behind a proxy server? (But checking `HTTPS` as well looks like a generic copy/paste solution?) If you're not behind a proxy, then that condition should probably be removed, since that header could potentially be faked. (?)

Note that it will be useful to *test* with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid erroneous redirects being cached by the browser. (Or test with browser caching disabled.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer this seems to be working, but when I access anything with the /video/ I get redirected to home page, any idea why?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file? Are you actually _redirected_ to the homepage, ie. you now see just `www.example.com/` in the browser's address bar? If you check the network traffic, what redirects do you see?